# Mac OSX Codesigning issues

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, codesign

I am experiencing a problem with codesigning on Mac OSX (Catalina and older), that I cannot find any answer for. I do have a *.component file, that I am codesigning and notarizing with my Apple Developer ID, which is working perfect. As a post-install step on the target machine, I need to include some installation info within the component's Info.plist (so I am writing back to that *.plist file), which would then qualify as a manipulation of the component itself - ergo, the component's signing is going to be corrupt at this point (the host software will not load my software any more).

So I was trying to follow some advice and do a "blind" codesigning as additional post-install step on the user's machine with:

```
sudo codesign --force --deep -s - ABC.component
```

This was just working perfect for a few users, just when I found out, not everyone can make use of this (especially older Mac OSX). Sometimes this command will just not result in a properly signed component. One of the users then found out, he had to update Xcode CL Tools, to sign the file. He went:

```
xcode.select --install
```

I have tested this with several other users and it worked with them, too.

**Here comes the issue**:

As a result, I need to make sure, the user has installed the right version of Xcode Command Line Tools, but a lot of my clients do install on an offline device - so I would not be able to have **xcode-select --install** as a post-install step (because no internet connection).

Is it somehow possible to bundle the proper Xcode Command Line Tools into my installer and make use of it? Or do you see any other solution for the whole problem?

Comment: _"As a post-install step on the target machine, I need to include some installation info within the component's Info.plist (so I am writing back to that *.plist file)"_ This is a very strange thing to do, and that appears to be the root of your problems.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? The language used to generate the binary to be signed seems irrelevant..

Comment: I understand, but it is needed. To be more clear: We are providing an Audio Units shell, that will need to know, which audio plugins a user has installed. The shell will then provide this info to the DAW host (e.g. Logic) --> Info.plist will store info about which plugins are installed, to not provide plugins, that are not. This can only be done after install, because the user is choosing during installation.

Comment: @JesperJuhl My fault, the *.component is coded in C++. You are right, it is not a specific C++ issue.

Comment: @AndréKirchner Why don't you sign everything just after you compile/build it?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Because I don't know, which parts of the software the user has installed. The component itself is a shell loader for a variety of bundles (which are chosen by the user on install) => The shell needs to know, which bundle files have been installed. The resulting Info.plist is manipulated and the signing therefore is going corrupt.

Comment: @AndréKirchner why does it matter what the user has installed if you just sign *everything* at build time? Then, whatever components the user installs, those components will be correctly signed. If you need a signature on "component combinations" (not quite sure what you *actually* need), could you then not create signatures for *all* possible component combinations at build time?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: This is also not possible (or I don't get it :/). It is 12 bundles, that are signed themselves, it is a shell component, that is signed on build time. Everything is packed into an installer and then codesigned & notarized. The user is installing it. As a post-install step, the component needs to understand, which bundle files are installed, because it is reporting this to a host application, when loaded from there (e.G. Logic Pro, ProTools, Cubase, etc.). I cannot create signed plist files, for every single combination of those 12 bundles.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Unfortunately, at this point I am bound to this, as I am not able to provide a short-term solution for this shell-type component. It has been working before, but it is broken with Mojave/Catalina.

Comment: @AndréKirchner can't you then, instead of verifying a "bundle signature", verify the individual signatures of the bundle components? And if they all check out the whole thing checks out? Also, why (except for extra compute resources needed) can't you generate signatures for all bundle variations?

Comment: @jesperJuhl, is it somehow possible to contact you directly? I could really use some help.

Comment: @JesperJuhl:
1.) I am not the one, who would verify the signature of the bundle/shell on the client's system, but his/her host software does. And this host software is looking at that one Info.plist <-- There is the info about installed plugins.
2.) Also, if I would provide all kinds of plist variations - how can I present the host software the right one? It is only looking for the single Info.plist and expecting the information there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204226/discussion-between-andre-kirchner-and-jesper-juhl).